# tab function on my sharepoint site wont stay open

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have code that I used from a site not the best coder out there but I try. I have this one code for Tabs and when I click the tab it does not stay open it closes to fast to read it, I think it has to do with my transition but not sure

Comment: What code? What version of sharepoint?

Comment: please add your code that is not working